# htaccess reqrite redirect conflict

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following code for a redirect on my website -

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$4
```

It works fine, but it doesn't pass on custom URL parameters to the new URL. So anything after `.com/?abc` just translates into `.com/` and results in an error in tracking.

I tried using `[QSA]` but it resulted in a redirect rewrite conflict in `.htaccess` I believe. What could be a possible way out?

Other codes on `.htaccess` include:

```
BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `RedirectMatch` with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*) http://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Example: 301s `http://mywebsite.com/1234/12/12/test?foo=bar` to `http://mywebsite.com/test?foo=bar`

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=ce6d907e-3559-5caf-8841-8f218d54f367

Comment: Tried that bananaapple, but mywebsite.com/?foo-bar still returns mywebsite.com/. I tried this on the website itself, since the demo link seemed to be giving an error upon trying the code out

Comment: Hm, looks like the share feature on the site is broken but you can still test on it by manually copy pasting in the bits. Anyway, the above should work so if it does not that suggests something else is interfering. One thing you could try is to put this at the very top so it gets processed first.

Comment: It's already on the top, so something else must be interefering with this code. Will keep trying. Thanks much for trying though :)

Comment: I also have this towards the bottom, should I try adding QSA with the L there?

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

So my issue has finally been solved. Looks like there was a conflict between manually set rules, w3total cache and/or yoast plugin. Disabling/removing them solved the issue.